# How to combine list object java?

Tags: java, list, object

I have two list object, I want combine them, this is my class

```
public class DailyIncome {

    private String date;
    private String total;

}
```

and I have two list, this is list A

[image]

and this is list B

[image]

and my expectation result like this

[image]

is possible to realize my expectation?

Comment: "... is it possible...?" -- yes, by writing some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Hmmm? what are you trying to do? I mean what is the bigger goal. It seems you are trying to resolve something bigger but you are using the wrong strategy

Comment: Your question is not even close to to the [mcve] you should have posted and there's a ton of ways to do this but you probably want to start by maybe changing your data to be more like `Map<Date, List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "is possible to realize my expectation?"

Yes, it is. But you'd better write down what you have tried so far before you ask a question in SO.

1, Your `DailyIncome` doesn't have Getter and Setter and the field is decorated with `private`. How would you expect it to be visited from other class?

2, For your scenario, I think `Map` should be used.

Please try the code below for your reference.

```
public class DailyIncome {
     public String date;
     public String total;

     public DailyIncome(String date, String total){
         this.date = date;
         this.total = total;
     }
}
```

And also the `Test` class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    private List<DailyIncome> shopA = new ArrayList<DailyIncome>();
    private List<DailyIncome> shopB = new ArrayList<DailyIncome>();
    private List<List<String>> shop = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    public void initialize(){
        shopA.add(new DailyIncome("20-08-16", "4"));
        shopA.add(new DailyIncome("21-08-16", "8"));
        shopA.add(new DailyIncome("23-08-16", "3"));

        shopB.add(new DailyIncome("20-08-16", "6"));
        shopB.add(new DailyIncome("21-08-16", "7"));
        shopB.add(new DailyIncome("22-08-16", "8"));
    }
    public void calculate(){

        Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(DailyIncome income: shopA){
            mapA.put(income.date, income.total);
        }

        for(DailyIncome income: shopB){
            mapB.put(income.date, income.total);
        }


        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
        keySet.addAll(mapA.keySet());
        keySet.addAll(mapB.keySet());

        Object keyArr[] = keySet.toArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++){
            String key = (String)keyArr[i];
            String totalA = mapA.containsKey(key) ? mapA.get(key):"0";
            String totalB = mapB.containsKey(key) ? mapB.get(key):"0";
            List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
            itemList.add(key);
            itemList.add(totalA);
            itemList.add(totalB);
            shop.add(itemList);
        }

        /*
         * print
         */
        for(List<String> itemList: shop){
            System.out.print(itemList.get(0) + "   ");
            System.out.print(itemList.get(1) + "   ");
            System.out.print(itemList.get(2));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.initialize();
        obj.calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow , you really helped me , thank you very much sir , case closed

Answer (score 1):

As @Tibrogargan said, it would be easier to combine them together if you didn't stock the data as a class, but as a Map. This is because Java would automatically read the data as a List of Dates, which then is associated with multiple Integers (income). I have done this many times, and have found that for **your** "issue", it would be easier to do what you want this way instead of by the way you first presented.

However, you should have your Map like this:

```
Map<Date, HashMap<ListId, Long>>
```

As you would be able to store the income for each list, and then if the results of a "get(ListId)" returns null, you know that no income will have came in for that list.

Hope this helps.
Sneling.

Answer (score -1):

I liked above two solutions! I think it can be done this way too if you are using java (by looking at provided example of DailyIncome):

Please try this: You will Just need to create list of DailyIncome instead of Integer.
        Collection id = Arrays.asList(2316, 2317, 2318);
        Collection existingId = Arrays.asList(1004, 1762, 1892, 1342, 1942, 2316);

```
    Collection<Integer> similar = new HashSet<Integer>( id );
    similar.addAll( existingId );


    System.out.println("Similar:"+similar);
```